# passing multiple values to a filter angularjs

Tags: angularjs

On ng-click of a `<div>` I am showing a particular `<div>` and doing some filtering. I need the filter to happen on more than one value.

In the code below I want something like

filter `if  evaluationStatusId == 11 or 12`

HTML :

```
<div style="font-size:40px;margin-top:10px" ng-click="clickedStatus='9'">
                                    {{Approved}}
</div>
 <div style="font-size:40px;margin-top:10px" ng-click="clickedStatus='10'">
                                    {{submitdMissnDocs}}
 </div>
<div style="font-size:40px;margin-top:10px" ng-click="clickedStatus='11 || 12'">
                                    {{Denied}}
 </div>

 <div class="row" name="empList" id="empList" ng-show="clickedStatus">
 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="emp in Summary.CorpEmployees | filter: {locationId:selectedItem.Label} | filter: {evaluationStatusId:clickedStatus}">
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) function like this:

```
$scope.myFilter = function(emp){

    return emp.locationid === $scope.selectedItem.Label || emp.evaluationStatusId === $scope.clickedStatus;

};
```

So your repeat expression would be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="emp in Summary.CorpEmployees | filter: myFilter">
```